# Finding Laplace transform of two functions multiplied together

Tags: laplace-transform

How can I find the Laplace of

$f(t) = \cos^2(t)$

$f(t) = \sin3t\cos3t$

$f(t) = te^{t}$

$f(t) = t\cos(2t)$

What about inverse transform for

$F(s) = \frac{5-3s}{2^s+9}$

$F(s) = \frac{10s-3}{25-s^2}$

$F(s) = 2s^{-1}e^{-3s}$

Is there a general method used when you're multiplying two functions together, or have what appears to be a combination in the inverse Laplace?  I was hoping I could look them up on a table of transforms, but I'm not exactly sure how to deal with them.

Comment: I think you should actually go and reply back to **all** the answers that were given to your questions and accept those answers before asking another question.

Comment: OK, I did.  I hope others will still help.

Comment: Also, you should give those answers a rate up so their reputation will increase, but to answer your question you should find the Laplace by using the definition, i.e, for $cos^2(t)$ you should use trig identities to help out with the integration. Also, for the inverse transform you should definitely use the table. Ask me if you still need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $L(e^{at})=\frac1{s-a}$

So putting $a=0,L(1)=\frac1s$

and putting $a=c+id,L(e^{(c+id)t})=\frac1{s-(c+id)}$

so, $L(e^{ct}\cos dt)+iL(e^{ct}\sin dt)=\frac{s-c+id}{(s-c)^2+d^2}$

$cos^2t=\frac{1+\cos2t}2$

So, $L(cos^2t)=\frac12 L(1)+\frac12 L(\cos2t)=\frac1{2s}+\frac s{2(s^2+2^2)}$

$\cos3t\sin3t=\frac{\sin6t}2$

So, $L(\cos3t\sin3t)=\frac{L(\sin6t)}2=\frac{6}{2(s^2+6^2)}$

We know, $L(e^{at}f(t))=F(s-a)$ where $F(s)=L(f(t))$

So, $L(e^{at} t^n)=\frac{n!}{(s-a)^{n+1}}$

Hence $L(te^t)=\frac1{(s-a)^2}$ putting $a=n=1$

Putting $a=2i,n=1; L(e^{2it} t)=\frac1{(s-2i)^2}$

$L(t\cos 2t)+iL(t\sin 2t)=\frac{(s+2i)^2}{(s^2+4)^2}=\frac{s^2-4+i4s}{(s^2+4)^2}$

Now compare the real and the imaginary parts.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's "Is there a general method used when you're multiplying two functions together, or have what appears to be a combination in the inverse Laplace?"

Comment: @tox123, Had the answer been accepted, if it didn't answer that?

Comment: @labbhatttacharjee It answered what the OP wanted (which was homework answers) not what the OP wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Use trig identities to help out with integration: $(cos(t))^2 = (1/2)(cos(2t) + 1)$

Which leads to: $L{(cos(t))^2} = L{(1/2)(cos(2t) + 1)} = (1/2)L{(cos(2t))} + (1/2)L{(1)}$

But we now have, $L{(1)} = L{(H(t))} = 1/s$ and $
L{(cos(2t))} = (1/2)L{(cos(t))}(s/2) = (1/2)(\frac{s}{4((s^2)} + 1)  = 2s/(s^2 + 4)$

Finally:

$$L{(cos(t))^2} = s/(s^2 + 4) + (1/2s) = (3s^2 + 4)/(2s)(s^4 + 4)$$

Comment: I did this on the fly because it is pretty late, I am not exactly sure if this is $100$% correct but if it is not I make sure to fix it by tmw.